# JQuery - using .on with element insertion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which creates a tooltip for specific objects. Currently, I am running a tooltip function after ajax insertions to create and append the new tooltip objects. I am curious if there is a way to use .on() to auto-run the tooltip function on insertion, rather than manually running it.

For instance:

```
 $('[title]').on('inserted', function(){
     tooltip(this);
 });
```

I did some reading and it looks like custom triggers might be the way to go, but I'd love if it something like this existed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the **pseudo** code as per request.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('added','*',function() {
        console.log($(this),'has been added');
    });
    $('body').append('<div>This is the first div</div>');
});

(function($) {
    fncs = {
        append:$.fn.append,
        appendTo:$.fn.appendTo
        // etc.
    }
    // we're assigning the original functions in this
    // object to be executed (applied) later
    $.fn.append = function() {
        fncs.append.apply(this,arguments);
        $(this).children().last().trigger('added');
        return $(this);
    }
    $.fn.appendTo = function() {
        fncs.appendTo.apply(this,arguments);
        return $(this);
        // no need to trigger because this function calls the one
        // above for some reason, and it's taking care of the
        // triggering the right element(s I think)
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Nice solution. This would be awesome if it was something built into jquery in the future, but this will do for now. Thanks!

Comment: You might wanna go through the whole list of functions for DOM manipulation in http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/. I'm hoping an implementation in a feature release, too.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the response you're looking for, but I would not attach tooltips directly on elements. Instead I would use a class for the ones I want the tooltip to show on mouseover and use the `.on()` event handler in the following way:

```
$('body').on('mouseover','.tooltip',function() {
    // show tooltip
    console.log($(this).data('tooltip'));
    return false;
}).on('mouseout','.tooltip',function() {
    // hide tooltip
    return false;
});
```

So that whatever you add to the body (not necessarily as a direct child) will trigger this event handler.

I would probably just create an additional function to assign the tooltip data to each element along with the class.

```
$.fn.extend({
    tooltip:function(text) {
        text = text || '';
        return $(this).each(function() {
            $(this).data('tooltip',text).addClass('tooltip');
        });
    }
});

$('#someID').tooltip("Click me!");
$('button').tooltip("I'm a button");
```

Comment: Good ideas, but yea not really the answer I was looking for. Tooltips was just an example, I run into this issue fairly often and was curious if there was a good solution. :)

Comment: Have you considered overriding the manipulation functions and triggering a custom event handler like 'added'?